# Typeset python setter decorators with the listing package

Tags: listings, python

I'm using the listing package to include my source files (Python) in my documentation but I'm having an issue with highlighting the setter decorators.

Decorators such as `@property` or `@dataclass` are easy enough, but I cannot get it to highlight setters such as `@r.setter` or `@g.setter`.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

After walking away from my desk for a bit I came up with this janky work-around - using the `morestring` option to identify each decorator, eg `morestring=[s][\color{orange}]{@r}{.setter}` or `morestring=[s][\color{orange}]{@data}{class}`.